# React- If uid not exist add to firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I have a code block for update user status. But I want to add to collection if user's uid not exist.
Here my code block sample:

```
const firestore = getFirestore();
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.on("value", function (snap) {
        if (snap.val() === true) {
            alert("connected");
            firestore
                .collection("presence")
                .where("uid", "==", auth.uid)
                .get()
                .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                        firestore
                            .collection("presence")
                            .doc(doc.id)
                            .update({ status: true });
                    });
                });
        }
```

Its work for only update status of user. I tried  [flutter - add to firestore collection if not exists otherwise update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58888939/flutter-add-to-firestore-collection-if-not-exists-otherwise-update) but not work me. Please hlp me.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for the existence of a single Firestore document,

```
const firestore = getFirestore();
const firebase = getFirebase();
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", async function (snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");

    const documentSnapshot = await firestore.collection("presence").doc(auth.uid).get();
    if (!documentSnapshot.exists) {
      await firestore.collection("presence").doc(auth.uid).set({ status: true });
    }

  }
  
}
```